# How to find the largest sum of consecutive terms of sequence of n positive and negative numbers?

Tags: python, divide-and-conquer

I was trying to solve this problem by splitting into halves and finding the largest sum in each. I used MegaSort. But I'm stuck on how to record and return back the largest sum from each recursive functions.
For example,

[1, -3, 4, -7, 8] -> the largest sum should be 8.(Sum of itself)

[5,5, -3,6, -10] -> the largest sum should be 5 + 5 + (-3) + 6 = 13

[3, -9, 10, 5] -> the largest sum is 10 + 5 = 15

```
 def find_max(seq):
     if len(seq) == 1:
        if(seq[0] > sum):
           sum = seq[0]
        return seq
     else:
        mid = len(seq)//2
        left = [:seq]
        right = [seq:]
        find_max(left)
        find_max(right)
```

Comment: I understand only a problem with your code. But what do you want to achieve? Please provide an input sequence, and the desired output. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this answer will be of any help as I understand your question is not about the algorithm itself but about how to implement it with Python(and I don't know Python). But there's another algorithm you could use that maybe you can implement without asking any help. Note that this algorithm computes only the sum, not the sequence that yelds that sum(as far as I understand this is what you want). Here is the C-like pseudocode solution:

```
int findMax(sequence, length) {

    int maxSumStartingAt[length]; 
    maxSumStartingAt[length - 1] = sequence[length-1];

    for(int i=length-2; i >= 0; i--) {
        int tempSum = sequence[i] + maxSumStartingAt[i+1];
        if ( sequence[i] > tempSum ) {
            maxSumStartingAt[i] = sequence[i];
        } else {
            maxSumStartingAt[i] = tempSum;
        }
   }

   int maxSum = maxSumStartingAt[0];
   for(int i = 1; i < length; i++) {
       if ( maxSum < maxSumStartingAt[i] ) {
           maxSum = maxSumStartingAt[i];
       }   
   }

   return maxSum;
}
```

Now I'll explain you how this solution works.

1) Since the subsequence that yields the largest sum must begin at some index i, the idea is to compute for every index i the largest sum of consecutive elements starting at i. The result is the maximum between these sums.

2) Now, if somebody told you that the subsequence of elements that yields the largest sum began at index i, and that the largest sum of consecutive elements for the subsequence beginning at index i+1 was x, how could you compute the desired sum? It would simply be the maximum between

```
sequence[i]
```

and

```
sequence[i] + x
```

We can use this information to compute the largest sum starting at index i for every index i: We begin from the last element of the sequence, aka

```
sequence[length-1]
```

if we start indexing from 0. What is the largest sum starting at this index, which I'll call maxSumStartingAt[length-1]? 
It can be none other than

```
sequence[length - 1]
```

itself since this is a 1-element sequence. And what is the largest sum starting at index length - 2? It's the maximum between

```
sequence[length-2]
```

and

```
sequence[length-2] + maxSumStartingAt[length-1]
```

And what is the largest sum starting at index length - 3? Again, it's the maximum between

```
sequence[length-3]
```

and

```
sequence[length-3] + maxSumStartingAt[length-2]
```

We can apply this formula to every index of the sequence, and eventually we get to index 0 and we have the largest sum beginning at the generic index i for every index. This is exactly what the first for loop in the solution does. At this point, all we have to do is find the maximum between all the computed sums(this is what the second for loop in the solution does). This maximum is the result.

One note on your solution. Given that I don't know Python so I can't judge  the code you posted, if it does exactly what you stated in the question(i.e splitting the sequence into two halves and computing the largest sum for every half, then returning the maximum between these two values) it does not work as it does not cover the case where the largest sum is yielded by a sequence that spans across the two halves.

Answer (score 0):

```
def largestSum(arr):
  curr = arr[0]
  lsum = arr[0]

  if len(arr) <= 1:
    return arr

  for i in range(1, len(arr)):
    curr = max(arr[i], curr + arr[i])

    if curr > lsum:
      lsum = curr
  return lsum

largestSum([-2,3,2,-1])
```